# How to rearrange subcategories?

Tags: product

I am new to magento, I have a column of products on my front magento page. I want to rearrange them to my liking as an administrator so they show up on the front end. I have tried everything but nothign seems to work.

Comment: could you share me screen shots of admin and front end side?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want to set product position on product list page, for this You have to navigate `Catalog->Manage Categories-> select any category` you will see **category Products tab**. From there, you will see the list of products that are associated to this category. The last column is **Position**.Where you can set the **position of products**.

[For more help see here.](http://inchoo.net/magento/changing-default-category-sort-order-in-magento/)